How to create reactive form in Angular 17
I have this HTML code:
 <form [formGroup]="billingFormGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
          <div class="row gy-3">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Ime</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg"formControlName ="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Unesite svoje ime">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" formControlName ="lastName" name="lastName">Prezime</label> 
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text"formControlName ="lastName" name="lastName" id="lastName" placeholder="Unesite svoje prezime">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Email</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" formControlName ="email" name="email"type="email" id="email" placeholder="e.g. Jason@example.com">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Broj telefona</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="tel" id="phone" placeholder="e.g. +381 6665544"formControlName ="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Ime kompanije(opciono) </label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="company" placeholder="Ime kompanije"formControlName ="companyName" name="companyName">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Adresa 1</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="address" placeholder="Postanski broj,ulica i broj"formControlName ="address1" name="address1">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Adresa 2</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="addressalt" placeholder="Sprat,zgrada,ulaz"formControlName ="address2"  name="address2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase" >Grad</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="city"formControlName ="city"  name="city"placeholder="Unesite grad">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
              <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase"  >Drzava</label>
              <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="state" formControlName ="state" name="state"placeholder="Unesite drzavu">
            </div>        
            <div class="col-lg-12 form-group">
              <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Porucite</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

This is my checkout.component.ts:
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormsModule, Validators,ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Order } from '../models/order.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
  styleUrl: './checkout.component.css',
})
export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit{

  billingFormGroup!:FormGroup
  order:Order = new Order()


constructor(){

}
  onSubmit() {
    this.order.firstName=this.billingFormGroup.get('firstName')?.value;
    this.order.lastName=this.billingFormGroup.get('lastName')?.value;
    this.order.email=this.billingFormGroup.get('email')?.value;
    this.order.phoneNumber=this.billingFormGroup.get('phoneNumber')?.value;
    if(this.billingFormGroup.get('companyName')?.value != null)this.order.companyName=this.billingFormGroup.get('companyName')?.value;
    if(this.billingFormGroup.get('address1')?.value != null)this.order.address=this.billingFormGroup.get('address1')?.value;
    if(this.billingFormGroup.get('address2')?.value != null)this.order.optionalAddress=this.billingFormGroup.get('address2')?.value;
    this.order.town=this.billingFormGroup.get('city')?.value;
    this.order.state=this.billingFormGroup.get('state')?.value;

    console.log(this.order)
    }
    

  ngOnInit(): void {
this.billingFormGroup=new FormGroup({
  'firstName':new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  'lastName':new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  'email':new FormControl('',[Validators.email]),
  'phoneNumber':new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  'companyName':new FormControl(''),
  'address1':new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  'address2':new FormControl(''),
  'city':new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  'state':new FormControl('',[Validators.required])
})
   
  }
}


The code is throwing me this error:
ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'firstName'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203
I've read something about ControlValueAccessor but i dont know how to implement it.
Can someone explain me why is Angular throwing me this error? Is it the new feature that is added in Angular 17 or something else because in previous versions I did not have any problem with forms?

Firstly a good number of your 2 way data binding [(ngModel)] are on the wrong element. They should be on the input & not the label.
Secondly, you are using both template driven & reactive form syntax in your linked code. I will assume you wish to use reactive forms given that is what your question seems to state.
When using reactive forms you should use the formControlName attribute instead of ngModel.
For example
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <label class="form-label text-sm text-uppercase"  name="lastName">Prezime</label> 
  <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Unesite svoje prezime" formControlName="lastName">
</div>


Yea i totally forgot to fix that.. Nevertheless i fixed it, created it using reactive forms but i still get this error:
main.ts:5 ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'lastName'. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG01203

I also updated this post with the right code so that you can see the code


Its because you still have formControlName attribute on your label (for the lastName field). You can only use formControlName on form elements (in this case your inputs) unless you implement control value accessor interface but this isn't required for what you are trying to do.

you can't bind ngModel to a label. Since label is not providing any control value
Remove [(ngModel)]="firstName" from;
<label class="form-label text-sm text-upperc
ase" [(ngModel)]="firstName" name="firstName">Ime</label>

And also, you shouldn't use ngModel inside reactive form.
Please read here
